# How to create multiple numbers of fields based on the value in one number field in Oracle Apex form?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working on a form in which I need to take numeric value from one field and based on that number(n) I need to create n fields for another column. How can I do so?

Comment: What is "field", and what is "column" in this context? Could you explain what problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps attach a scanned drawing of what you'd like to accomplish? Looks like something "dynamic", but - I'm not sure what would that be (nor whether it is possible or not).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use APEX_ITEM API if I understand your task right:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/APEX_ITEM.html

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT APEX_ITEM.TEXT(rownum)
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY rownum < :YOUR_ITEM;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to create `n` page items in a **declarative** way. APEX simply wasn't made for this.

I can think of two workarounds:

1. Use a plsql dynamic content region to generate html with the `apex_item` package just like Ivan Dubashinskii suggested. You will need to submit the page in order to have the region re-generate your page items when the amount `n` is changed. There are some downsides to this approach, as for example it won't be that simple to use your page items in a page process.
2. Just limit your page items to some number, like 10. Then, create 10 page items in a declarative way and use dynamic actions to show/hide them when `n` changes. This way, it will also be much easier to use your items in a page procress.